# Add a program exit before a while loop in java

Tags: java

I can't get the program to stop and display the message below if a -1 is entered to kill the loop before it starts.  The program will also, not flow in to the while loop if a different integer is entered.  I seem to have misplaced my curly brackets somewhere because the last 2 get errors.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    double score;
    double total = 0.0;
    double average;
    int scoreCount = 0;

    // create the Scanner object. Name it stdin
    Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

    // title at the top of the output
    System.out.println (" score report");;

    do{
    //   read the first score
        System.out.printf ("Enter a score  (1-100, -1 to quit)"
            + ": ", scoreCount);
        score = stdin.nextDouble();

        if (score == -1)
        {
            System.out.println ("Nothing entered.");
        }           
    while((score = stdin.nextDouble()) != -1.0)
    {              
        if (score<-1 || score>100)
        {
        System.out.println ("Illegal score.  Try again");
        System.out.printf ("Enter a score  (1-100, -1 to quit)"
              + ": ", scoreCount);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.printf ("Enter a score  (1-100, -1 to quit)"
              + ": ", scoreCount); 
            scoreCount++;
            total += score;
        }        
           // end of for loop
    average = total / scoreCount;       //equation
    System.out.printf ("\nThe average score for %d students is %8.2f\n",
                          scoreCount, average); 
    }
} // end of main
```

} // end of class definition

Comment: is your code compiling?

Comment: Anytime you have a problem with a piece of code, it is best to use the ide's debugger. If you are in Netbeans click on the line number you suspect to be problematic, or in eclipse double click. The ide's debugger is one of programmings best friends.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I understand, the problem has a simple solution. To exit the loop, simply use `break`:

```
if (score == -1)
{
    System.out.println ("Nothing entered.");
    break;
}
```

Also, based on the code, the "do" statement isn't really required. Simply use a regular while loop.

Comment: Hmm I could get that, but it still wouldn't go in to the while loop if a different number is pressed

Comment: replace `return` with `break`

Comment: Right, didn't see "the message below" in the question. Thanks!

Comment: I tried that and it still doesn't prompt the user to add another number to go in the loop

Answer (score 0):

You need a "while" condition at the end of your do loop. This is why it is called a do-while loop. Without the while condition, you should get a compile-time error. Here is an example:

```
double score;
double total = 0.0;
double average;
int scoreCount = 0;

// create the Scanner object. Name it stdin
Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

// title at the top of the output
System.out.println ("Score Report");

 do{
  //   read the first score
      System.out.println("Enter a score (0-100 or -1 to quit)" 
            + ": " + scoreCount);
      score = stdin.nextDouble();//Retrieve the score.

      if(score == -1) {
        System.out.println("Bye!");
       }

      if (score<-1 || score>100)//Here is the if statement that makes the user enter another score if it is illegal
      {
        System.out.println("Illegal score.  Try again");
        continue; //A continue statement will start the loop over again from the top!
      }
      else if(score >= 0 && score <= 100 && score != -1)
      {

            scoreCount++;
            total += score;
       }        
      // end of for loop
      average = total / scoreCount;       //equation
      System.out.println();
      System.out.printf ("\nThe average score for %d students is %8.2f\n",
                          scoreCount, average); 
      System.out.println();
}while(score != -1); //Runs "while" the score != -1
```

Here is a sample of the possible output of this program:

```
Score Report
Enter a score (0-100 or -1 to quit): 0
50.0


The average score for 1 students is    50.00

Enter a score (0-100 or -1 to quit): 1
50.0


The average score for 2 students is    50.00

Enter a score (0-100 or -1 to quit): 2
-90
Illegal score.  Try again
Enter a score (0-100 or -1 to quit): 2
50.0


The average score for 3 students is    50.00

Enter a score (0-100 or -1 to quit): 3
-1
Bye!


The average score for 3 students is    50.00
```

As you can see here, you if statement changes to:

```
if (score<-1 || score>100)//Here is the if statement that makes the user enter another score if it is illegal
        {
        System.out.println("Illegal score.  Try again");
        continue;
        }
```

The continue statement will force the loop to start at the beginning without executing the rest of the code in the loop. This will help you avoid invalid input. 
At the end of the do loop you also need this while condition:

```
 }while(score != -1);
```

Now the loop will only continue so long as the score is not equal to negative 1. If the score is equal to -1, you can also inform the user that they are exiting the program in your code:

```
if(score == -1) {
            System.out.println("Bye!");
        }
```

You can change your else statement to an else if statement to execute if the numbers entered are in the range of 0 to 100, or else the -1 entry would be counted as a score:

```
else if(score >= 0 && score <= 100 && score != -1)
        {

            scoreCount++;
            total += score;
        }        
           // end of for loop
```

You're also not exiting your loop like you say you are above. The average will be counted every time you iterate through your loop. Put the code that displays the average outside of your loop:

```
}while(score != -1);
    average = total / scoreCount;       //equation
    System.out.println();
    System.out.printf ("\nThe average score for %d students is %8.2f\n",
                      scoreCount, average);
```

Now the output will look something like this:

```
Score Report
Enter a score (0-100 or -1 to quit): 0
50.0
Enter a score (0-100 or -1 to quit): 1
70.0
Enter a score (0-100 or -1 to quit): 2
90.0
Enter a score (0-100 or -1 to quit): 3
-1
Bye!


The average score for 3 students is    70.00
```

If you want a message to be displayed ONLY when -1 is entered as the first option do:

```
if(score == -1 && scoreCount == 0) {
            System.out.println("Bye!");
        }
```

Comment: I can get the program to quit after -1 is pressed.  I just want a special case where if it is pressed as the first option it displays a message.  If it is pressed after a few numbers, to just do the calculations.

Comment: @Moca
    if(score == -1 && scoreCount == 0) {
             System.out.println("Bye!");
            }

Comment: @Moca I edited my answer at the bottom. If scoreCount is 0 (meaning no score has been added yet) you are still on the first iteration, so have the message displayed at that time by creating an "and" condition

Comment: I understand much better now I know what I did wrong now. Thank for for all the effort

Answer (score 0):

The code as posted will not compile. Here is a correct function to enter a bunch of numbers from 0 to 100 and calculate the average. The program will quit when -1 is entered. I have added comments to the code.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    double score;
    double total = 0.0;
    double average;
    int scoreCount = 0;

    // create the Scanner object. Name it stdin
    Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

    // title at the top of the output
    System.out.println (" score report");

    //Request the first score
    System.out.printf ("Enter a score %d  (1-100, -1 to quit)"
            + ": ", scoreCount+1);
    //read the first score
    score = stdin.nextDouble();
    do{
        //check the entered score and decide what to do. 
        if (score == -1)
        {
            System.out.println ("Nothing entered.");
            break;
        } else if (score<-1 || score>100)
        {
            System.out.println ("Illegal score.  Try again");
            System.out.printf ("Enter a score %d  (1-100, -1 to quit)"
                    + ": ", scoreCount+1);
        }
        else
        {
            scoreCount++;
            total += score;
            // The entered score is good ask for the next one
            System.out.printf ("Enter a score %d  (1-100, -1 to quit)"
                    + ": ", scoreCount+1);
        }        
    }while((score = stdin.nextDouble()) != -1.0); // Here we read the input. 
    // end of the program.
    average = total / scoreCount;       //equation
    System.out.printf ("\nThe average score for %d students is %8.2f\n",
            scoreCount, average); 
} // end of main
```

Comment: Oh so move the stuff I have under the while right now, to the do part ? and just make the while when the program meets the certain criteria.

Comment: the original  do { .. } while();   was incorrect. do { ... } while () {} will not compile, at least not with Exclipse.

I hope the in code comments helped.

Comment: Ok I understand now thank you very much for the help!  I see where I messed up.

Comment: Please up vote my answer, I'm trying to get a bit more involved with Stackoverflow.

Comment: I did.  It just doesn't show because my standing isn't high enough =)

Comment: @Moca, can you click on the check mark below the vote counter, see if it will accept this as the correct answer.